# Convert Object Array List into String Array

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, arraylist

Currently I have the below code, where I am trying to cast from Object to String and I get an exception error.

What is the best way to convert from this Object array to String array so that it will work in my for loop? Or is there a way to alter my for loop to display the Object array?

```
<%

          Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/Users/rhysparker/Documents/workspace/Resource_Planner/WebContent/db/RESOURCE.SQLITE");
                Statement stat = conn.createStatement();

                ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> al = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

                ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("select project_name from project;");

                ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
                int columns = metaData.getColumnCount();

                while (rs.next()) {
                    ArrayList<String> record = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                        String value = rs.getString(i);
                        record.add(value);
                    }
                    al.add(record);
                }

                String[] testing = (String[])al.toArray();

                for(int i=0;i<testing.length;i++) 
                { %> 
                <option value="<%=testing[i]%>"><%=testing[i]%></option><% 
                } 

                rs.close();
               conn.close();
            %>
```

Comment: what exception it is throwing?

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 I get an exception error.
```

Yes because `al` is type of `ArrayList<String>`
 `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> al = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();`

And  your are casting it to a array of string

```
String[] testing = (String[])al.toArray();
```

so it will throw exception at run time like .

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
```

If you are adding `Arraylist` inside arraylist then its your responsibility to insure type checking.

You can do something like following :

```
for (ArrayList<String> list: al)
 {
    String[] testing = list.toArray(new String[0]); // or (String[]) arr.toArray();
    for(int i=0;i<testing.length;i++) 
     { %> 
        <option value="<%=testing[i]%>"><%=testing[i]%></option><% 
     }
 }
```

Comment: That is just what I am looking for. I will study up on array lists to get a better understanding. Thanks for your help Sumit.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
String[] array = (String[])list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

You mean something like this?Try this.

Comment: That throws the same exception. java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `al` is multidimensional (ArrayList of ArrayList -- containing a database table -- I suppose)
Below code will help you in filling your `testing` array

```
int maxColumn = 100;    //Assuming not more than 100 columns
int rowSize = a1.size();
String[] s1 = new String[maxColumn];
String[][] testing = new String[rowSize][maxColumn];    
for(int i=0; i<rowSize; i++)
{
    ArrayList a1 = al.get(i);
    s1 = a1.toArray();
    for(int j=0; j<s1.length; j++)
        testing[i][j] = s1[j];
}
```

`testing` is the 2-dimensional array which has the table record. Now to which column you need to assign
in your `<option>` field that matters
Say you need to assign `column 3`
So your `for-loop` will become

```
for(int i=0;i<rowSize;i++) 
{ %> 
    <option value="<%= testing[i][3] %>"><%=testing[i]%></option>
<% }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an exception because the elements inside the arraylist `al` that you are converting is of type `ArrayList<String>` which, ofcourse, cannot be cast to `String[]`.

You must use 2 dimensional array for your code to work because your list `al` is of type `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` which means the elements inside your list is another list that contains `String`

To solve your problem, you must manually loop through your list then convert each element (which is `ArrayList<String>`) into `String[]`

```
int yLen = al.size();
        int xLen = al.get(0).size();
        String[][] testing = new String[yLen][xLen];
        for(int a = 0; a < yLen; a++){
            testing[a] = al.get(a).toArray(testing[a]);
        }
```